# Unable to apply changes on device: Error is: cp: cannot create directory '/platforms/android/app/src': No such file or directory

Tags: nativescript, angular2-nativescript

`tns run android --bundle` is giving me following error:

Unable to apply changes on device:***. Error is: cp: cannot create directory '**/platforms/android/app/src': No such file or directory.

and then the next line is:

```
Stopping webpack watch
```

If I delete platforms folder and then run above command then it does not give any error.

I have deleted `node_modules`, `hooks`, `platforms` folders and then tried to run but didn't work.

I have tried upgrade webpack to the latest version but It didn't work.

Here is my package.json

```
{
  "nativescript": {
    "id": "org.nativescript.cloint",
    "tns-ios": {
      "version": "4.2.0"
    },
    "tns-android": {
      "version": "4.2.0"
    }
  },
  "description": "NativeScript Application",
  "license": "SEE LICENSE IN <your-license-filename>",
  "repository": "<fill-your-repository-here>",
  "scripts": {
    "lint": "tslint \"src/**/*.ts\""
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "~6.1.0",
    "@angular/common": "~6.1.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "~6.1.0",
    "@angular/core": "~6.1.0",
    "@angular/forms": "~6.1.0",
    "@angular/http": "~6.1.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~6.1.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~6.1.0",
    "@angular/router": "~6.1.0",
    "nativescript-angular": "~6.1.0",
    "nativescript-camera": "^4.0.3",
    "nativescript-iqkeyboardmanager": "^1.3.0",
    "nativescript-permissions": "^1.2.3",
    "nativescript-secure-storage": "^2.3.0",
    "nativescript-snackbar": "^3.2.0",
    "nativescript-theme-core": "~1.0.4",
    "nativescript-ui-sidedrawer": "~4.3.0",
    "nativescript-web-image-cache": "^4.2.6",
    "reflect-metadata": "~0.1.10",
    "rxjs": "~6.2.0",
    "tns-core-modules": "~4.2.0",
    "tns-platform-declarations": "^4.2.1",
    "zone.js": "~0.8.18"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "~6.1.0",
    "@nativescript/schematics": "~0.3.0",
    "@ngtools/webpack": "~6.2.0",
    "codelyzer": "~4.3.0",
    "nativescript-dev-sass": "~1.6.0",
    "nativescript-dev-typescript": "~0.7.0",
    "nativescript-dev-webpack": "^0.16.0",
    "tslint": "~5.11.0",
    "typescript": "~2.7.2"
  },
  "readme": "NativeScript Application"
}
```

The main problem is that every time I need to remove the platform folder in order to run the project.

Here is full console after running `tns run android --bundle`

```
~/Projects/production/cloint [requests] $ tns run android --bundle
Skipping node_modules folder! Use the syncAllFiles option to sync files from this folder.
Searching for devices...
Starting Android emulator with image Nexus_5X_API_25
Waiting for emulator device initialization...
Executing before-liveSync hook from /Users/rahulgavande/Projects/production/cloint/hooks/before-liveSync/nativescript-angular-sync.js
Executing before-watchPatterns hook from /Users/rahulgavande/Projects/production/cloint/hooks/before-watchPatterns/nativescript-dev-sass.js
Executing before-watchPatterns hook from /Users/rahulgavande/Projects/production/cloint/hooks/before-watchPatterns/nativescript-dev-typescript.js
Executing before-watchPatterns hook from /Users/rahulgavande/Projects/production/cloint/hooks/before-watchPatterns/nativescript-dev-webpack.js
Executing before-watch hook from /Users/rahulgavande/Projects/production/cloint/hooks/before-watch/nativescript-dev-sass.js
Hook skipped because bundling is in progress.
Executing before-watch hook from /Users/rahulgavande/Projects/production/cloint/hooks/before-watch/nativescript-dev-typescript.js
Hook skipped because bundling is in progress.
Executing before-watch hook from /Users/rahulgavande/Projects/production/cloint/hooks/before-watch/nativescript-dev-webpack.js
Running webpack for Android...
clean-webpack-plugin: /Users/rahulgavande/Projects/production/cloint/platforms/android/app/src/main/assets/app/**/* has been removed.
File change detected. Starting incremental webpack compilation...

Webpack is watching the files…

Hash: 68c900ccb3e606cb9949
Version: webpack 4.6.0
Time: 24946ms
Built at: 2018-10-30 11:47:05
                                                                               Asset        Size  Chunks             Chunk Names
  App_Resources/Android/src/main/res/drawable-xhdpi/baseline_arrow_back_white_18.png   171 bytes          [emitted]
                                                                           bundle.js    62.1 KiB  bundle  [emitted]  bundle
                                                                                1.js    6.48 KiB       1  [emitted]
                                                                                2.js    69.6 KiB       2  [emitted]
                                                                           vendor.js    5.05 MiB  vendor  [emitted]  vendor
                                                    App_Resources/Android/app.gradle   549 bytes          [emitted]
                                                 App_Resources/Android/src/.DS_Store       6 KiB          [emitted]
                                  App_Resources/Android/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml    1.36 KiB          [emitted]
                     App_Resources/Android/src/main/res/drawable-hdpi/background.png    3.42 KiB          [emitted]
          App_Resources/Android/src/main/res/drawable-hdpi/baseline_add_white_18.png   150 bytes          [emitted]
          App_Resources/Android/src/main/res/drawable-hdpi/baseline_add_white_24.png   138 bytes          [emitted]
          App_Resources/Android/src/main/res/drawable-hdpi/baseline_add_white_36.png   158 bytes          [emitted]
          App_Resources/Android/src/main/res/drawable-hdpi/baseline_add_white_48.png    97 bytes          [emitted]
   App_Resources/Android/src/main/res/drawable-hdpi/baseline_arrow_back_white_18.png   160 bytes          [emitted]
   App_Resources/Android/src/main/res/drawable-hdpi/baseline_arrow_back_white_24.png   171 bytes          [emitted]
   App_Resources/Android/src/main/res/drawable-hdpi/baseline_arrow_back_white_36.png   176 bytes          [emitted]
   App_Resources/Android/src/main/res/drawable-hdpi/baseline_arrow_back_white_48.png   203 bytes          [emitted]
                           App_Resources/Android/src/main/res/drawable-hdpi/icon.png     6.8 KiB          [emitted]
                           App_Resources/Android/src/main/res/drawable-hdpi/logo.png    32.4 KiB          [emitted]
                           App_Resources/Android/src/main/res/drawable-hdpi/menu.png   291 bytes          [emitted]
                     App_Resources/Android/src/main/res/drawable-ldpi/background.png    1.31 KiB          [emitted]
                           App_Resources/Android/src/main/res/drawable-ldpi/icon.png    3.23 KiB          [emitted]
                           App_Resources/Android/src/main/res/drawable-ldpi/logo.png    9.95 KiB          [emitted]
                           App_Resources/Android/src/main/res/drawable-ldpi/menu.png   213 bytes          [emitted]
                     App_Resources/Android/src/main/res/drawable-mdpi/background.png    1.89 KiB          [emitted]
          App_Resources/Android/src/main/res/drawable-mdpi/baseline_add_white_18.png   102 bytes          [emitted]
          App_Resources/Android/src/main/res/drawable-mdpi/baseline_add_white_24.png    92 bytes          [emitted]
          App_Resources/Android/src/main/res/drawable-mdpi/baseline_add_white_36.png   138 bytes          [emitted]
          App_Resources/Android/src/main/res/drawable-mdpi/baseline_add_white_48.png    97 bytes          [emitted]
   App_Resources/Android/src/main/res/drawable-mdpi/baseline_arrow_back_white_18.png   128 bytes          [emitted]
   App_Resources/Android/src/main/res/drawable-mdpi/baseline_arrow_back_white_24.png   132 bytes          [emitted]
   App_Resources/Android/src/main/res/drawable-mdpi/baseline_arrow_back_white_36.png   171 bytes          [emitted]
   App_Resources/Android/src/main/res/drawable-mdpi/baseline_arrow_back_white_48.png   170 bytes          [emitted]
                           App_Resources/Android/src/main/res/drawable-mdpi/icon.png    3.42 KiB          [emitted]
                           App_Resources/Android/src/main/res/drawable-mdpi/logo.png    15.8 KiB          [emitted]
                           App_Resources/Android/src/main/res/drawable-mdpi/menu.png   235 bytes          [emitted]
                 App_Resources/Android/src/main/res/drawable-nodpi/splash_screen.xml   304 bytes          [emitted]
                    App_Resources/Android/src/main/res/drawable-xhdpi/background.png    5.26 KiB          [emitted]
         App_Resources/Android/src/main/res/drawable-xhdpi/baseline_add_white_18.png   138 bytes          [emitted]
         App_Resources/Android/src/main/res/drawable-xhdpi/baseline_add_white_24.png    97 bytes          [emitted]
         App_Resources/Android/src/main/res/drawable-xhdpi/baseline_add_white_36.png    97 bytes          [emitted]
         App_Resources/Android/src/main/res/drawable-xhdpi/baseline_add_white_48.png   102 bytes          [emitted]
                                                                                0.js    11.8 KiB       0  [emitted]
  App_Resources/Android/src/main/res/drawable-xhdpi/baseline_arrow_back_white_24.png   170 bytes          [emitted]
  App_Resources/Android/src/main/res/drawable-xhdpi/baseline_arrow_back_white_36.png   203 bytes          [emitted]
  App_Resources/Android/src/main/res/drawable-xhdpi/baseline_arrow_back_white_48.png   261 bytes          [emitted]
                          App_Resources/Android/src/main/res/drawable-xhdpi/icon.png    10.4 KiB          [emitted]
                          App_Resources/Android/src/main/res/drawable-xhdpi/logo.png      54 KiB          [emitted]
                          App_Resources/Android/src/main/res/drawable-xhdpi/menu.png   297 bytes          [emitted]
                   App_Resources/Android/src/main/res/drawable-xxhdpi/background.png    10.3 KiB          [emitted]
        App_Resources/Android/src/main/res/drawable-xxhdpi/baseline_add_white_18.png   158 bytes          [emitted]
        App_Resources/Android/src/main/res/drawable-xxhdpi/baseline_add_white_24.png    97 bytes          [emitted]
        App_Resources/Android/src/main/res/drawable-xxhdpi/baseline_add_white_36.png   186 bytes          [emitted]
        App_Resources/Android/src/main/res/drawable-xxhdpi/baseline_add_white_48.png   113 bytes          [emitted]
 App_Resources/Android/src/main/res/drawable-xxhdpi/baseline_arrow_back_white_18.png   176 bytes          [emitted]
 App_Resources/Android/src/main/res/drawable-xxhdpi/baseline_arrow_back_white_24.png   203 bytes          [emitted]
 App_Resources/Android/src/main/res/drawable-xxhdpi/baseline_arrow_back_white_36.png   253 bytes          [emitted]
 App_Resources/Android/src/main/res/drawable-xxhdpi/baseline_arrow_back_white_48.png   275 bytes          [emitted]
                         App_Resources/Android/src/main/res/drawable-xxhdpi/icon.png    20.3 KiB          [emitted]
                         App_Resources/Android/src/main/res/drawable-xxhdpi/logo.png     116 KiB          [emitted]
                         App_Resources/Android/src/main/res/drawable-xxhdpi/menu.png   378 bytes          [emitted]
                  App_Resources/Android/src/main/res/drawable-xxxhdpi/background.png    3.87 KiB          [emitted]
       App_Resources/Android/src/main/res/drawable-xxxhdpi/baseline_add_white_18.png    97 bytes          [emitted]
       App_Resources/Android/src/main/res/drawable-xxxhdpi/baseline_add_white_24.png   102 bytes          [emitted]
       App_Resources/Android/src/main/res/drawable-xxxhdpi/baseline_add_white_36.png   113 bytes          [emitted]
       App_Resources/Android/src/main/res/drawable-xxxhdpi/baseline_add_white_48.png   116 bytes          [emitted]
App_Resources/Android/src/main/res/drawable-xxxhdpi/baseline_arrow_back_white_18.png   203 bytes          [emitted]
App_Resources/Android/src/main/res/drawable-xxxhdpi/baseline_arrow_back_white_24.png   261 bytes          [emitted]
App_Resources/Android/src/main/res/drawable-xxxhdpi/baseline_arrow_back_white_36.png   275 bytes          [emitted]
App_Resources/Android/src/main/res/drawable-xxxhdpi/baseline_arrow_back_white_48.png   408 bytes          [emitted]
                        App_Resources/Android/src/main/res/drawable-xxxhdpi/icon.png    73.8 KiB          [emitted]
                        App_Resources/Android/src/main/res/drawable-xxxhdpi/logo.png     193 KiB          [emitted]
                        App_Resources/Android/src/main/res/drawable-xxxhdpi/menu.png   466 bytes          [emitted]
                     App_Resources/Android/src/main/res/drawable/baseline_add_24.xml   384 bytes          [emitted]
              App_Resources/Android/src/main/res/drawable/baseline_arrow_back_24.xml   411 bytes          [emitted]
                            App_Resources/Android/src/main/res/values-v21/colors.xml   104 bytes          [emitted]
                            App_Resources/Android/src/main/res/values-v21/styles.xml  1020 bytes          [emitted]
                                App_Resources/Android/src/main/res/values/colors.xml   237 bytes          [emitted]
                                App_Resources/Android/src/main/res/values/styles.xml    1.68 KiB          [emitted]
                                                               fonts/FontAwesome.ttf     162 KiB          [emitted]
                                                               assets/login-logo.png    11.8 KiB          [emitted]
                                                                     assets/logo.png    16.3 KiB          [emitted]
                                                                        package.json    82 bytes          [emitted]
                                                                          starter.js    39 bytes          [emitted]
                                                                 tns-java-classes.js     0 bytes          [emitted]
[../$$_lazy_route_resource lazy recursive] ../$$_lazy_route_resource lazy namespace object 160 bytes {bundle} [built]
[./app.scss] 21.3 KiB {bundle} [built]
[./app/app-routing.module.ts] 791 bytes {bundle} [built]
[./app/app.component.html] 3.18 KiB {bundle} [built]
[./app/app.component.ts] 4.64 KiB {bundle} [built]
[./app/app.config.ts] 1.89 KiB {bundle} [built]
[./app/app.http-interceptor.ts] 1.4 KiB {bundle} [built]
[./app/app.module.ts] 1.33 KiB {bundle} [built]
[./app/login/login.module.ts] 773 bytes {0} [built]
[./main.ts] 620 bytes {bundle} [built]
[./package.json] 82 bytes {bundle} [optional] [built]
[./services/feedback.service.ts] 552 bytes {bundle} [built]
[./services/login.service.ts] 1.95 KiB {bundle} [built]
[./services/master.service.ts] 1.18 KiB {bundle} [built]
[./services/storage.service.ts] 1.22 KiB {bundle} [built]
    + 472 hidden modules
Webpack compilation complete. Watching for file changes.
Webpack build done!
Executing before-shouldPrepare hook from /Users/rahulgavande/Projects/production/cloint/hooks/before-shouldPrepare/nativescript-dev-webpack.js
Executing before-cleanApp hook from /Users/rahulgavande/Projects/production/cloint/hooks/before-cleanApp/nativescript-dev-webpack.js
Executing before-prepare hook from /Users/rahulgavande/Projects/production/cloint/hooks/before-prepare/nativescript-dev-sass.js
Hook skipped because either bundling or livesync is in progress.
Executing before-prepare hook from /Users/rahulgavande/Projects/production/cloint/hooks/before-prepare/nativescript-dev-typescript.js
Hook skipped because either bundling or livesync is in progress.
Preparing project...
Executing before-prepareJSApp hook from /Users/rahulgavande/Projects/production/cloint/hooks/before-prepareJSApp/nativescript-dev-webpack.js
Gradle clean...
         + setting applicationId
         + applying user-defined configuration from /Users/rahulgavande/Projects/production/cloint/App_Resources/Android/app.gradle
         + adding nativescript runtime package dependency: nativescript-optimized-with-inspector
         + adding aar plugin dependency: /Users/rahulgavande/Projects/production/cloint/node_modules/nativescript-camera/platforms/android/nativescript_camera.aar
         + adding aar plugin dependency: /Users/rahulgavande/Projects/production/cloint/node_modules/nativescript-ui-sidedrawer/platforms/android/TNSSideDrawer-release.aar
         + adding aar plugin dependency: /Users/rahulgavande/Projects/production/cloint/node_modules/nativescript-web-image-cache/platforms/android/nativescript_web_image_cache.aar
         + adding aar plugin dependency: /Users/rahulgavande/Projects/production/cloint/node_modules/nativescript-ui-core/platforms/android/TNSCore-release.aar
         + adding aar plugin dependency: /Users/rahulgavande/Projects/production/cloint/node_modules/tns-core-modules-widgets/platforms/android/widgets-release.aar
Unable to apply changes on device: emulator-5554. Error is: cp: cannot create directory '/Users/rahulgavande/Projects/production/cloint/platforms/android/app/src': No such file or directory.
Executing after-watch hook from /Users/rahulgavande/Projects/production/cloint/hooks/after-watch/nativescript-dev-sass.js
Executing after-watch hook from /Users/rahulgavande/Projects/production/cloint/hooks/after-watch/nativescript-dev-typescript.js
Executing after-watch hook from /Users/rahulgavande/Projects/production/cloint/hooks/after-watch/nativescript-dev-webpack.js
Stopping webpack watch
```

Comment: Which version of CLI you are using?

Comment: Nativescript CLI version is `4.2.4`

Comment: Since you deleted platform folder do a fresh tns platform add Android . If you want bundle see if Webpack is included in package.json

Comment: After adding platform it runs fine for one time. But after that, it gives me the same error.

Comment: I have added console logs, maybe it helps.

Comment: @RahulGavande Do you have a playground link for this app?

Comment: try setting permission sudo chmod -R 755 /Users/rahulgavande/Projects/production/cloint/platforms/android/app/src

Answer (score 0):

I had the exact same problem after following the upgrade guide:

https://docs.nativescript.org/releases/upgrade-instructions

After first launch (which works) set the permissions:
sudo chmod -R 755 platforms/android/

Thanks Narendra for the hint.

This must be done everytime your relaunch "tns run android --build"